# Java Junit 4 test case for draw for tic tac toe 8 by 8 board

Tags: java, junit4

hi i'm having trouble with creating a test case for draw, I made an 8 by 8 tic tac toe board where user input numbers from 0 to 7 for row and column with player x going first. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to create a test case to check for draw.

```
 package cpsc.tictac.test;

 import org.junit.Test;
 import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestGameBoard {



    /************************************************************

     Test checkSpace


     ************************************************************/

    @Test
    public void testcheckSpace_row1_column10() {

        GameBoard gb = new GameBoard();
        BoardPosition b = new BoardPosition(1, 10, 'X');
        assertFalse(gb.checkSpace(b));


    }

    /************************************************************

     Test checkWinner

     ************************************************************/

    @Test
    public void testcheckforWinner_row1() {
        BoardPosition b = new BoardPosition(0, 0, 'X');
        BoardPosition b1 = new BoardPosition(0, 1, 'X');
        BoardPosition b2 = new BoardPosition(0, 2, 'X');
        BoardPosition b3 = new BoardPosition(0, 3, 'X');
        BoardPosition b4 = new BoardPosition(0, 4, 'X');
        GameBoard gb = new GameBoard();
        gb.placeMarker(b);
        gb.placeMarker(b1);
        gb.placeMarker(b2);
        gb.placeMarker(b3);
        gb.placeMarker(b4);

        assertTrue(gb.checkForWinner(b4));

    }

@Test
public void testcheckforWinner_column1() {
    BoardPosition b = new BoardPosition(0, 0, 'X');
    BoardPosition b1 = new BoardPosition(1, 0, 'X');
    BoardPosition b2 = new BoardPosition(2, 0, 'X');
    BoardPosition b3 = new BoardPosition(3, 0, 'X');
    BoardPosition b4 = new BoardPosition(4, 0, 'X');
    GameBoard gb = new GameBoard();
    gb.placeMarker(b);
    gb.placeMarker(b1);
    gb.placeMarker(b2);
    gb.placeMarker(b3);
    gb.placeMarker(b4);

    assertTrue(gb.checkForWinner(b4));

   }


@Test
public void testcheckforWinner_diagonal1() {
    BoardPosition b = new BoardPosition(1, 1, 'X');
    BoardPosition b1 = new BoardPosition(2, 2, 'X');
    BoardPosition b2 = new BoardPosition(3, 3, 'X');
    BoardPosition b3 = new BoardPosition(4, 4, 'X');
    BoardPosition b4 = new BoardPosition(5, 5, 'X');
    GameBoard gb = new GameBoard();
    gb.placeMarker(b);
    gb.placeMarker(b1);
    gb.placeMarker(b2);
    gb.placeMarker(b3);
    gb.placeMarker(b4);

    assertTrue(gb.checkForWinner(b4));
}



    /************************************************************

     Test checkDraw

     ************************************************************/

    @Test
    public void testcheckForDraw() {



             NEED HELP HERE





        }
    }
```

in my program my way to check draw is

```
 public boolean Draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (table[i][j] == ' ')
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why does `checkForWinner()` take a board-position as an argument ?

Comment: if the player has 5 in a row then they win. I made it so that after that board position it should assert true

Comment: you are answering a different question than the one that I asked...

Comment: do you verify draw after verifying the winning condition first?

Comment: any updates? @j.rodes

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `Draw()` method (btw, avoid having methods with capital starting letter), you need a full board without any player to win.

```
private char[][] boardWithDraw = 
   {{'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0'},
    {'0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'},
    {'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0'},
    {'0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'},
    {'0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'},
    {'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0'},
    {'0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X'},
    {'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', '0'}};
```

As you can see, there are no more then 4 of the same sing on the diagonal, even less on row/column. This is a draw.

Now you just traverse this 2D array and fill up your `GameBoard` with `BoardPosition`'s from this input.

Defining some algorithm, which would generate this array would make your test very unreadable.